# Mutate dummy variable with observation before and after

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable, panel-data

I've a title-day panel data set (df1). For every title and given day the volume (volume) is coded. There is a variable that you could see as a treatment (v1). In this dataset there is always a treatment, but the day the treatment starts differs per title. When the treatment starts, it stays till the end of the period.

```
title <- rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each = 5)
day <- rep(c(0,1,2,3,4), times = 3)
volume <- c(0,0,1,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,4,2,1)
v1 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
df1 <- data.frame(title,day,volume,v1)
```

I try to mutate a dummy variable that indicates whether the title got any volume (non zero) before AND after the treatment is in place. Where 1 is coded in situations when the title got volume before and after the treatment started. 0 is coded when the title got no volume before or no volume after the treatment started. The dataframe should look like this:

```
title <- rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each = 5)
day <- rep(c(0,1,2,3,4), times = 3)
volume <- c(0,0,1,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,4,2,1)
v1 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
new_v <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
output <- data.frame(title,day,volume,v1,new_v)
```

Hope you guys can help me out here.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly it is because the volume on all the treatment days is 0 for `y`

Comment: Exactly Dominik. It's 0 because there should be volume before and after treatment. Y has only volume before treatment but no after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(title, v1) %>% 
  mutate(summe = sum(volume)) %>% 
  group_by(title) %>% 
  mutate(dummy_volume = all(summe > 0)) %>% 
  select(-summe)

# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   title [3]
   title   day volume    v1 dummy_volume
   <fct> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>       
 1 x         0      0     0 FALSE       
 2 x         1      0     0 FALSE       
 3 x         2      1     1 FALSE       
 4 x         3      1     1 FALSE       
 5 x         4      2     1 FALSE       
 6 y         0      3     0 FALSE       
 7 y         1      0     1 FALSE       
 8 y         2      0     1 FALSE       
 9 y         3      0     1 FALSE       
10 y         4      0     1 FALSE       
11 z         0      3     0 TRUE        
12 z         1      3     0 TRUE        
13 z         2      4     0 TRUE        
14 z         3      2     1 TRUE        
15 z         4      1     1 TRUE
```

With the Dummy coded as 0/1 as in your desired output:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(title, v1) %>% 
  mutate(summe = sum(volume)) %>% 
  group_by(title) %>% 
  mutate(dummy_volume = as.integer(all(summe > 0))) %>% 
  select(-summe)

# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   title [3]
   title   day volume    v1 dummy_volume
   <fct> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>        <int>
 1 x         0      0     0            0
 2 x         1      0     0            0
 3 x         2      1     1            0
 4 x         3      1     1            0
 5 x         4      2     1            0
 6 y         0      3     0            0
 7 y         1      0     1            0
 8 y         2      0     1            0
 9 y         3      0     1            0
10 y         4      0     1            0
11 z         0      3     0            1
12 z         1      3     0            1
13 z         2      4     0            1
14 z         3      2     1            1
15 z         4      1     1            1
```

Comment: I choose this answer for its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ave` and make a case handling using `if/else` when all treated `volumes` are zero.

```
output <- transform(df1, new_v=ave(volume, title, FUN=function(x) {
  rr <- sum(x[v1 %in% 0], na.rm=T) > 0
  if (sum(x[v1 %in% 1], na.rm=T) == 0) 0
  else rr
}))
#    title day volume v1 new_v
# 1      x   0      0  0     0
# 2      x   1      0  0     0
# 3      x   2      1  1     0
# 4      x   3      1  1     0
# 5      x   4      2  1     0
# 6      y   0      3  0     0
# 7      y   1      0  1     0
# 8      y   2      0  1     0
# 9      y   3      0  1     0
# 10     y   4      0  1     0
# 11     z   0      3  0     1
# 12     z   1      3  0     1
# 13     z   2      4  0     1
# 14     z   3      2  1     1
# 15     z   4      1  1     1
```

Or if you need `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
output <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(new_v=ave(volume, title, FUN=function(x) {
  rr <- sum(x[v1 %in% 0], na.rm=T) > 0
  if (sum(x[v1 %in% 1], na.rm=T) == 0) 0
  else rr
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

For every `title` we can check if there is `any` `volume > 0` before treatment (`v1 == 0`) and after treatment (`v1 == 1`).

This can be done using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(title) %>%
  mutate(new_v = +(any(volume[v1 == 1] > 0) && any(volume[v1 == 0] > 0)))

#  title   day volume    v1 new_v
#   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 x         0      0     0     0
# 2 x         1      0     0     0
# 3 x         2      1     1     0
# 4 x         3      1     1     0
# 5 x         4      2     1     0
# 6 y         0      3     0     0
# 7 y         1      0     1     0
# 8 y         2      0     1     0
# 9 y         3      0     1     0
#10 y         4      0     1     0
#11 z         0      3     0     1
#12 z         1      3     0     1
#13 z         2      4     0     1
#14 z         3      2     1     1
#15 z         4      1     1     1
```

Or the same logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, new_v := +(any(volume[v1 == 1] > 0) && 
                        any(volume[v1 == 0] > 0)), title]
```